# Java FTPS Problems

Tags: java, apache, ftps

Still unanswered. Any and all help is appreciated!

I am using Apache Commons-Net3.1 and trying to get the FTPS working. When I try to connect, I am getting the following errors in the console :

---EDIT: CODE AND ERRORS UPDATED---

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:192)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:285)
```

I am sure I am just not setting up it up right. Here is my code. Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. (I am trying to connect via port 990 by the way). The code errors at the line "client.connect(ftpHost);"

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MyFTP {
 public void downloadFTP(){

        FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(false);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        client.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());

        try {
            client.connect(ftpHost);
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            client.login(ftpUser, ftpPassword);


            String filename = "liveGUIfile.txt";
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);


            client.retrieveFile("/root/Desktop/" + filename, fos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a security problem. What host are trying to reach? By the way, it is not the same SFTP that FTP

Comment: @jddsantaella, im trying to reach another computer that i have vsftpd setup on (long story of why i need to do it this way, but i do). I was able to get it working successfully in a c# program i wrote.

Comment: Note that while vsftpd does seem to support SSL, it's probably not on by default, and certainly needs configuration.

Comment: Code and errors updated.

Answer (score 3):

FTPS may be explicit or implicit, you use explicit:

> ```
> FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(false);
> ```

But explicit one usually uses 21 port, like FTP does, and implicit one uses 990 port. So try to connect to 21 port or to use `new FTPSClient(true)`

Answer (score 0):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

That says it all. Plaintext connection. You are connecting to an FTP server, not an FTPS server. It's right there in the error message.

Comment: Well, it is an FTPS server, as i used FTPS in a c# program and had to trust all certificates. I have updated my question with new code and new errors.

Comment: Does the server listen on port 21 or 990 ?